# Plotly: How to change the default mode bar button?

Tags: r, plotly, config

I am generating plotly graphics and using shinyapps to publish COVID data from my country.

But when I generate the plot **the default modebar button is the "zoom" function and it makes complicated its use on a smartphone**:

[image]

I need the "Pan" function is the default button but I could find the solution.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just include:

```
fig <- fig %>% layout(dragmode='pan')
```

This will change your default activated menu option from...

[image]

... to:

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
x <- c(1:100)
random_y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
data <- data.frame(x, random_y)

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~random_y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')

fig <- fig %>% layout(dragmode='pan')
fig
```

I hope this is what you were looking for! Don't hesitate to let me know if not.

Comment: What if I want the box select option as the default?

Comment: Old but I had the same problem @Athe. You can use `layout(p, dragmode="select")`. Check the layout documentation in #dragmode: https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/